# Execute Rule directly (working around Rules + Workflow)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is there a way to execute a Rules action in code?

I have a set of rules that e-mail the author when a certain Workflow state has been arrived at.  In pseudo Rules logic:

```
Event: After updating existing content
IF NOT [node:workflow-old-state-name] == [node:workflow-current-state-name]
AND [node:workflow-current-state-name] == Published
DO E-mail Author
```

Which works just fine.  Except, I invoke `workflow_execute_transition` directly in some places.  This doesn't execute my rule because it's not `After updating existing content`.  I'd like to manually execute my rule's action (bypassing the conditions) after I call `workflow_execute_transition`.  Possible?

This all feels like a bit of a workaround.  Why doesn't Rules have triggers for Workflow State Changed?  Workflow is properly represented in core's Trigger module, but not here in Rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... turns out Rules **does** have a `Workflow state has changed` event.  I was just a version behind.

So that solves this problem, now that `workflow_execute_transition` is properly triggering the rule.

Much cleaner now!